# react-chartjs-2 doesn't work in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I'm trying to create a Bar chart using chartjs and react-chartjs-2.
The chart component worked in javascript react, but now I need to use it in typescript and it returns an error:

```
TypeError: Comp is not a function
```

This is the bar component:

```
import { Chart as ChartJS} from 'chart.js/auto';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';


export default function BarChart({product_data}:any) {

    const bar_data = {
        labels: ["Positive Reviews", "Neutral Reviews", "Negative Reviews"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "Number of reviews",
            data: [product_data.pos_count,product_data.neut_count,product_data.neg_count],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 0.5,
        }]
    }
   

  return (
      <Bar  data={bar_data} />
  )
}
```

I installed @types/chart.js and @types/react-chartjs-2 and its still not working, could anyone help me?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

**React + TypeScript**

You need to change:

`import { Chart as ChartJS} from 'chart.js/auto';`

to

`import 'chart.js/auto';`

Answer (score -1):

Chart.js comes with build in typings so you need to uninstall both the types packages then it will work fine.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAcgMYAsCGsB0ArAzgejQFcYIEBuAWAChRJY4AlAUzSXgDMoIREpX2FGnWjwA3nABCGOAF84XHnwEwAtKgww8qgExDqNGswAe9eABNmHYgBtORAHbtgEB1IwBhdLAAUYsNzmROwA+uZoMGiyAFxoDgCeAJRwYobUcBlwSK648ABGGGERaHAAvCk0mVVwNmh5zDa40XAA2gBEAAoQuMAwwABuzEzM-cDMAO64bQA0cG0AcswkUGg2w6MTU7MLzADmEQNDLBuTbQC605XVGeGRuMwwTa2p6dfVtfU2zQtEIPVQcAgHDg-BOWyub0ytzQzRaAQgQVC0MwkFwIWyjhg03hiJgRUimAcSzxGIcWJxwTxyKJu3REExFwhkLgBSQAGtdtxHOYPBAbNBYUzmZkEFBdgUfAB2ACsswAjABOHTypWzAAMmB0iQQl1ewqqovFaB8OmlsrgOjVADZZgAOG1wDVanVC5mGiWm80KhXygDMysdmu1ruujL1zLy0EsUF5-KggvD+r4Rql5sVAfT8u1uqTBrFHrNs0tDvtWZdibd+eNntm3r9GeDFdDOf1kag0YA6sBzDAUM0NbKQ3IzkzZBC0hl+DAiFA3D5XQAeaQAuDQ0piApQfFROD4AB8V0SNFkQA

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work

Comment: It seems to work fine as you can see in my TS playground I added to my answer so if its not working please add a reproducable sample